# "Take" vs "take away"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, verbs, word-difference

To take away can mean: **to get a particular message or piece of information from something you read or are told.**

**Example:**

> - What I **took away** from his talk is that going to university is definitely worth it.

My question is that whether normally people use "take away" or just "take" without "away"?

Because I know that both simple and phrasal verbs are used in this sense, but I doubt if one of them is more common or somehow more informal...

i.e. in my provided example above, substituting the sentence with the following sentence will change the message?

> - What I **took** from his talk is that going to university is definitely worth it.

For me, both of the sentences convey the same meaage.

Please let me know about them.

Comment: I see no difference in the two.

Comment: Both are unusual meanings, and do not feature in the major dictionaries. I'd be inclined to use the word 'got' rather than either of these two. An Ngram search produced so few references that it's hardly reliable, but 'got' came out marginally ahead and 'took' scored no hits at all. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got+from+the+meeting%2Ctook+away+from+the+meeting%2Ctook+from+the+meeting&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgot%20from%20the%20meeting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctook%20away%20from%20the%20meeting%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Thank you @JavaLatte, but I wonder if you could have a look on the third definition in this link: https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/take-sth-away

Comment: I find nothing unusual with those phrases. You can also say *The takeaway from his talk is . . .* Speaking only personally, I would use *what I took away*. it sounds more figurative. As opposed to *what I took*, which sounds more like what would be used if you had stolen the presentation notes (or something similar).

Comment: Thank you very much @Jason Bassford; therefore sayin: "(**My take on his talk** OR **My takeaway from his talk**) is that going to university is definitely worth it." sounds idiomatic to you?

Comment: Yes, *my take on his talk* is also natural. (I'd prefer that to *my takeaway from his talk*, but I've heard both.)

Comment: Oh, @Jason Bassford; I forgit to ask about the verbal state of "take on"! Please also let me know whether I can say: "What dis you **take on his behavior**."? Does this usage sound natural to you?

Comment: *What did you take on his behaviour* doesn't make sense to me. But *What is your take on his behaviour?* would be fine.

Comment: _Takeaway_, the noun, and _to take away_ are very commonly used in speech among young people in North America. But they are **colloquial** and somewhat __informal__. So Google Ngrams, which is based on written texts, might not tell you much about them.

Comment: @A-friend _My **take** on that subject_ and _my **takeaway** from that talk_ mean different things! See the definition on [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take) (or any other major dictionary). See sense 1 under noun. Someone's **take** means someone's opinion, view, or assessment of, or approach to something. **Takeaway** is the information you get from a source, e.g. a talk, lecture, book. They could overlap in certain contexts, but essentially they mean different things.

Comment: Thank you Eddie Kal for the informative reply, but I would appreciate if you make an answer and explain it in more details.

Comment: Well @JavaLatte, I guess you mean that I should say something like: "what **did you get** from his words?" Or "What I **got** from his talk is that going to university is definitely worth it." But what should I use as a **noun**? E.g. "Your...........is wrong. I didn't mean that."

Comment: Also, please tell me more about the two sentences: "Don't **take** it the wrong way", while I think based on your statements, **"get"** can work properly instead of **"take"** in this sentence and it would be natural to say:  "Don't **get** it the wrong way". So both sentences should be idiomatic and normal. Am I right? :)

Comment: You wouldn't say "your ..... is wrong"... it's too confrontational. You would say "you've got the wrong end of the stick"... this suggests that the person has simply made a mistake. For "don't take it the wrong way", look at the ACCEPT meaning in the Cambridge Dictionary. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take